# How to open Tor using Python Selenium on Windows

Tags: python, windows, selenium, driver, tor

Is there any way to open TorBrowser via Selenium on Windows? I tried many things from other similar questions:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

binary = FirefoxBinary(r"C:\Users\usr\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe")
profile = FirefoxProfile(r"C:\Users\usr\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default")

self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, binary, executable_path=r'C:\TestFiles\geckodriver.exe')

# yes, I have TB on desktop
# I also tried some other code, but everything gives me the same result
```

And the only result what I get is:

> Tor failed to start.
>           |OK|

and after clicking ok:

[image]

Also, the code "works" only when I give executable_path, in argument.
Where may be the problem? How to open TorBrowser on Windows using Python Selenium? 
I use Python 3.8, Windows 7, newest TorBrowser 9.5 and geckodriver v0.26.0 (I think)
And I need the TorBrowser, not only things that TorBrowser do, like IP changing.